# control and monitor proxy server IPv4

Tags: server, proxy, monitoring, ipv4

There is a private proxy server IPv4 and 1 port. It is possible to use HTTPS or SOCKS5. It will be used on multiple computers (configuration at the browser level, not a PC). DNS server shared (CloudFlare)

Since I am the owner of this proxy, I want to control and monitor it, namely to see:

- the number of devices using it at the moment (online)
- workload on proxy, traffic
- What sites each computer runs

What of this is possible and with what tools? Is there a general solution (one tool) for all tasks?

Is VPS / VDS required for such purposes? If not, how is an addition than he can be useful?

Answer (score 0):

From present:

- [Tinyproxy](http://tinyproxy.github.io/) can generate static html file with you needs.
- [Artica Proxy](https://www.articatech.com/index.php) has a web front end with statistics. Users and transit and sites.

From the past (not maintained):

- [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/): can generate static html file with your needs.